# vb.net update each row with a specific value

Tags: database, vb.net

I want to build a loop in vb.net that update the price into the database.
Final Goal is to build a API that takes the price and insert into the Database where ID is dynamic

Today goal is to build a loop that insert 1 into the table "price" where ID is 1 - 4
But i want to be the price dynamic
But when i click the button it shows the right syntax but he dont update.

Can you give me tips or tricks to help me.
I read something with the DataAdapter but i dont have a clue.

Code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        pgConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=magic;User Id=magic;Password=magic;"      'PostgreSQL connection'
        pgConnection.ConnectionString = pgConnectionString
        pgCommand.Connection = pgConnection
        pgCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim apiid As Integer

        apiid = 1

        Do While apiid <= 4
            pgConnection.Open()
            pgCommand.CommandText = "update magic set price = 1 where ID=" & apiid & ""
            pgConnection.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(pgCommand.CommandText)
            apiid += 1
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're never executing the command. After setting the commandtext you need to do something like pgCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Thank you, i see what i did wrong i programm another button with:"reader = pgCommand.ExecuteReader".

Comment: ExecuteReader is for processing rows returned from the database. ExecuteNonQuery is for operations like update, insert, delete. The call to ExecuteNonQuery needs to go inside your loop, after you set the commandtext.

Comment: Take a look at http://dapper-tutorial.net

Comment: You should always use parameters with ADO.NET rather than string concatenation. If you're going to execute a command in a loop, add the parameter once and then set its `Value` on each iteration. Also, that should be a `For` loop. If you want to do something for a series of incrementing numerical values then a `For` loop is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here that you probably want to be doing a bit of reading about. but I think this should get you started

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    pgConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=magic;User Id=magic;Password=magic;"      'PostgreSQL connection'
    pgConnection.ConnectionString = pgConnectionString
    pgCommand.Connection = pgConnection
    pgCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim apiid As Integer

    apiid = 1

    Do While apiid <= 4
        pgConnection.Open()
        pgCommand.CommandText = "update magic set price = 1 where ID=" & apiid & ""

        pgCommand.ExecteNonQuery() 'As per comments above

        pgConnection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(pgCommand.CommandText)
        apiid += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Other things you're going to want to consider is both connection and command objects implement IDisposable, so Using statements would be a good idea to handle the connection state and garbage collections for you.  Next, you're going to want to read up on using parameters.  This will allow you to keep you're price dynamic as your initial requirements, it's a lot less prone to errors and finally, it's a introduces an element of security to protect your DB integrity (SQL Injections)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better not to mix you User Interface code with your database code.

I created a class for the price data.

```
Public Class NewPrice
    Public Price As Double
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Sub New(p As Double, i As Integer)
        Price = p
        ID = i
    End Sub
End Class
```

The database code might look like the following. Connections should be created and disposed in the method where they are used. The `Using...End Using` block ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed. The constructor of the connection can take the connection string as an argument; likewise the command can take the sql statement and the connection as arguments.

Before the loop we create the connection and command and the connection is opened. Only the values of the parameters change inside the loop

```
Private ConStr As String = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=magic;User Id=magic;Password=magic;"

Public Sub UpdateMagicPrice(PriceList As List(Of NewPrice))
    Using cn As New NpgsqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("update magic set price = @Price where ID= @ID", cn)
        cn.Open()
        For Each np In PriceList
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", NpgsqlDbType.Double).Value = np.Price
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = np.ID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

In the User Interface code we create the list of your data.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim p As Double = 13.95
    Dim lst As New List(Of NewPrice)
    For i = 1 To 4
        lst.Add(New NewPrice(p, i))
    Next
    UpdateMagicPrice(lst)
End Sub
```

I hope this gets you started to your goal.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your feedback i move to the Backgroundworker